# function address cast to char array

Tags: c, function, casting, memcpy

For my educational purposes I was wondering if there is an alternative way with memcpy() to the following code for the function address casting to an array of chars?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef void (*_vfp)(void);
#define FPSZ sizeof(_vfp)


union rcast {
    _vfp fp;
    char fp_c[FPSZ];
} rc;
void a(void){
    printf("a()\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i=0;
    memset(&rc,0,FPSZ);

    rc.fp=a;
    for (i=0;i<FPSZ;++i)
    printf("%hhx ",rc.fp_c[FPSZ-i-1]);  
    puts("");
    printf("%p\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `memset(&rc,0,FPSZ);` - why not use `sizeof(rc)`?

Comment: You want to copy data into where the function code resides? That's a read-only memory segment, you'll get a bus fault (memory access violation during runtime).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimally modifying your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef void (*_vfp)(void);
#define FPSZ sizeof(_vfp)

void a(void){
    printf("a()\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i=0;
    _vfp fp = a;
    char fp_c[FPSZ];
    memcpy(fp_c, &fp, FPSZ);
    for (i=0;i<FPSZ;++i)
    printf("%hhx ",fp_c[FPSZ-i-1]);  
    puts("");
    printf("%p\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: In response to comment, here's a version without a proxy and without memcpy

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef void (*_vfp)(void);
#define FPSZ sizeof(_vfp)

void a(void){
    printf("a()\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i=0;
    char fp_c[FPSZ];
    for (i=0;i<FPSZ;++i)
    fp_c[i] = (char) (((uintptr_t) &a) >> CHAR_BIT * i);
    for (i=0;i<FPSZ;++i)
    printf("%hhx ",fp_c[FPSZ-i-1]);  
    puts("");
    printf("%p\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. And now I'm curious if there is a way to avoid use of a "proxy" fp, i.e. memcpy(array, (some casting) fp, FPSZ). It happens that fp always decays to a pointer and I copy the first bytes of instructions.

Comment: Not with memcpy, because you need to pass the *address* of some value to be copied, so the value to be copied has to be stored somewhere.

Comment: Updated with a version without memcpy and without a proxy.

Comment: Note that the no-memcpy version always stores the fp_c in little-endian representation while the memcpy version stores it in host representation (which happens to be little endian for x86 family cpus)

Comment: Yes, it is. However, there are specific rules about when you can use a pointer casted back from an integer to dereference.

Answer (score 0):

> For my educational purposes I was wondering if there is an alternative way with memcpy() to the following code for the function address casting to an array of chars?

Note well: though arrays and pointers are closely associated, they are very different things.  Among many other differences, you can use pointer types in cast operators, and pointers as cast operands, but you cannot use array types or arrays in those contexts.

You seem to say that what you want is a char array containing the bytes of the function pointer's value (as opposed to the bytes of whatever the pointer points to).  You can get that, or something like it, several ways.  The simplest way is to create a `char *` to the pointer's value.  Again, that's *not* an array, but it can be used in many of the same ways that an array could be used:

```
typedef void (*_vfp)(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    _vfp fp = a;
    char *cp = &fp;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(fp); ++i) {
        printf("%hhx ", cp[i]);
    }
    printf("\n%p\n", (void *) a);
    return 0;
}
```

Do note, however, that the above code exhibits undefined behavior.  The `%p` field descriptor tells `printf()` that the corresponding argument is an *object* pointer.  C draws a distinction between object pointers and function pointers, and does not define any behavior for converting between values of those two type families.  I include a cast explicitly expressing such a conversion (which may enable the compiler to notice and complain); your code results in such a conversion being performed implicitly.

If you want a separate array object containing the bytes of the pointer's value (as opposed to the pointed-to function's), then you can get it in a similar way:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    _vfp fp = a;
    char array[sizeof(fp)];

    memcpy(array, &fp, sizeof(array));

    /* ... */    
}
```

That one uses `memcpy()`, exactly as you asked.

In any event, there is no need for a union.  In fact, although your union-based approach might happen to work with your C implementation, reading from a different union member than was most recently written to formally exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: I know that casting trough union is undefined in C  and was looking for a way with memcpy(). And now I'm curious if there is a way to avoid use of a "proxy" fp, i.e. memcpy(array, (some casting) fp, FPSZ). It happens that fp always decays to a pointer and I copy the first bytes of instructions.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is formally Undefined Behaviour. C language says that an union can contain any of different variables, but you shall only access the variable that was set in the union : *The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of its members. The value of at
most one of the members can be stored in a union object at any time.* (ref : C Language Specification Draft - 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers - 16)

So it is neither best nor worse than doing pointer casting via void :

```
intptr_t ip = (intptr_t) &a;
char *fp_c = (void *) &intptr_t;
```

or with `memcpy` :

```
char fp_c[FPSZ];
intptr_t ip = (intptr_t) &a;
memcpy(fp_c, &ip, sizeof(intptr_t));
```

All will give you same result in :

```
for (i=0; i<FPSZ; i++) {
    printf("%hhx ",fp_c[FPSZ-i-1]);
}
fputs("\n");
```